# Airflow: Mark execution date range task istances as success

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that has run tasks for over a decade of execution dates. Now I needed to add another year to the beginning. I googled a little bit and the recommendation was to do this under a new dag_id. Because the old DAG has run already for that named execution date range, I want to mark those in the new DAG as a success. How can I archive this in a convenient way?

Thanks in advance. Have a nice start to this week.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow's [backfill feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-ref.html#backfill) is designed to do exactly what you're trying to do.

That said, not everyone likes using the feature.  For example, if your dag is ordinarily an hourly job, backfilling several years of data in hourly batches might be really inefficient.

So for various reasons, creating a temporary "backfill" dag is not a bad way to go.

And to be clear, with "backfill" dag I refer to a dag you are using for *purpose* of backfill, while *not* using airflow backfill *feature*.

For your "backfill" dag, use the DAG parameters `start_date` and `end_date` to control the range of `execution_date` a dag will create dag runs for.

Then after your "backfill" dag is done with all its runs, you can delete it.  Airflow won't know the old task instances are now backfilled, but you may not care about that.  If you do, you can update the `dag_id` manually in the metastore database.  And otherwise, your "old" dag has correct metadata for more recent periods.